# mongodb vs nodejs remove duplicat from several fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, duplicates

After several unsuccessful attempts directly with mongodb aggregation, i switched to nodejs to perform this task, i manage to delete duplicates documents based on a single field, i would like to be able to delete duplicates documents based on several fields, my lack of experience with nodejs not letting me successfully complete this task, can someone help to remove duplicates based on several fields ?

here is my current code,

index.js :

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
require("dotenv").config();

async function removeDups() {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    const DB = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const coll = DB.collection(process.env.COLL_NAME);
    const tempColl = DB.collection(process.env.TEMP_COLL_NAME);
    await tempColl.createIndex({ [process.env.UNIQUE_FIELD]: 1 }, { unique: true });
    const data = coll.find();
    const total = await data.count();
    let count = 0;
    let dupCount = 0;
    data.forEach(async (item) => {
      try {
        await tempColl.insertOne({ ...item });
        count++;
        console.log("Succesfuly Copied " + count + " unique documents.");
      } catch (error) {
        //Catch duplicate error and ignore, any other error panic.
        dupCount++;
      }
      if (count + dupCount == total) {
        console.log("Inserted " + count + " unique documents and removed "+ dupCount+" duplicates.");
        await DB.renameCollection(process.env.COLL_NAME,"temp_collection_review")
        await DB.renameCollection(process.env.TEMP_COLL_NAME,process.env.COLL_NAME)
        client.close();
        process.exit(1);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

removeDups();
```

.env :

```
DB_URL = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
```

```
DB_NAME = test
```

```
COLL_NAME = test
```

```
UNIQUE_FIELD = user
```

```
TEMP_COLL_NAME = products_temp
```

(source: https://github.com/ceodigvijay/mongodb-remove-duplicates)

Comment: `const data = await coll.find();` you are missing `await` here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get document with same 3 fields in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75086394/get-document-with-same-3-fields-in-a-collection)

Comment: it does not really match given that it searches in all the files for identical values ​​and exports the results, here we need to target specific fleds by name

Comment: This looks like a perfect use case for [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

Comment: $merge are not easy to use whit multiple targeted fields, can you help to build aggregation ? given that the nodejs solution is currently working fine with a single file, i think it would be best to change my current code, thanks